# (Not) Downloading Patches?

Tags: vmware-esx

I have just upgraded from VC 2.5 U4 to vSphere Server 4 U1. I have upgraded the Upgrade Manager extension also.

My patch repositry shows what looks to be a full repositry, it contains ESX 3.5 patches and ESX 4 patches, BUT, if I look at the actual directory structure of downloaded patches then there are no ESX 4 patches downloaded??

Why hasnt it downloaded all the patches? Running the scheduled task doesnt do it and there are no error's when it runs. There is also no email confirmation anymore after running - presumably as nothing has been downloaded.

Cheers,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

Try completely uninstalling and delete VCUM, clear down all directories etc, reboot then reinstall.

Comment: I've never realized how dirty VCUM could be ...